# How to deploy the WCF service to Azure for use in windows phone?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7, azure, windows-phone-8

I have developed a WCF service which modifies the db table which is also there in the cloud.

Now to deploy this service in cloud do I need to have a Azure project or can I directly deploy this.

And also I want this service to monitor the db table in the cloud and whenever there is a record modified in the db table.IS there a way we can trigger the service when a table is modified ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now. ITs under cloud services in VS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy in the cloud, you will need an Azure project with a WebRole for your WCF service. When you create the project, the wizard allows you to select the type of Role you want to include.

Comment: Though I installe SDK , the Azure Project template is not visible in installed templates .